# Select a item into a combobox issue

Tags: vb.net

Okay, I'm going crazy. I created a code capable of passing parameters contained in a combobox from the form1 to form2. All working good but when I enter in this function: http://pastebin.com/XpSfYybe
the value of Combobox2 and 3 of the form1 isn't readed correctly, in particular I get a blank message.

```
If statusString = True Then
            MessageBox.Show(Form1.MetroComboBox3.SelectedItem)
            MetroComboBox3.SelectedItem = Form1.MetroComboBox2.SelectedItem
            MetroComboBox4.SelectedItem = Form1.MetroComboBox3.SelectedItem
            statusString = False
        End If
```

The variable statusString is used to view if the user has pressed a button, if the button is pressed so the value of statusString go to True.
I also tried with a form instance, to get exception but doesn't working.
The funny thing is that if I execute `Messagebox.Show(Form1.MetroCombobox3.SelectedItem)`in a button code or in a other functions, the value appears correctly!
Why in `update_team` the code fails to get value of Combobox of the form1?
I don't understand the reason. Nb: the value of the combobox is equal in both form, in fact I execute the adding before of condition that I previously posted.

Comment: Form1 seems to be a reference to default Form1 instance. If you have created a different instance of Form1 (IE new Form1()) then you are referencing a different instance without any item in its comboboxes. You should reference the exact instance where the comboboxes are initialized and filled with items.

Comment: but like I said if I run Messagebox.Show(Form1.MetroCombobox3.SelectedItem) out the update_function the content is correctly readed. The same code.

Comment: didnt you just ask this earlier today?

Comment: Yes, but I deleted the question to add further details and content so as to obtain a good solution and solve the problem.

Comment: use explicitly instanced forms and get rid of the empty Try/Catch

Comment: For explicitly instanced forms you intend Dim frm as new Form1? Because I've already tried this with the exceptions block try/catch and nothing has worked.

Comment: Out of curiosity, the method Update_Teams belongs to which class? (and yes, do not put empty try/catch blocks because if an exception occurs you will never know and you will not be able to identify problems. At least display the exception message)

Comment: the *only* reason you wont get a value back if there is something there is if you are not referencing the same form instance.

Comment: I also remove the try/catch block and nothing works. Another hint?

Comment: How about `MetroComboBox3.SelectedIndex = Form1.MetroComboBox2.SelectedIndex`? By the way, _Harold_. How's Reese holding up? :D